Trouble Creating a Custom TensorFlow Dataset Using COCO Annotations and Images
I have downloaded the coco 2017 dataset and have all files (annotations, training, validation, ...) available. In order create a dataset to train my tensorflow model I have written the class CocoDataset.
class CocoDataset:
    def __init__(self, annotation_file, image_dir):
        self.coco = COCO(annotation_file)
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.img_ids = list(self.coco.imgs.keys())

    def load_image_and_annotations(self, image_id):
        # Load image metadata
        img_data = self.coco.loadImgs(image_id)[0]
        img_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, img_data["file_name"])
        #tf.print("Loaded image data:", img_path)

        # Read and decode image
        img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)

        # Original image dimensions
        original_height = img_data['height']
        original_width = img_data['width']        

        # Resize image to 640x640
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [640, 640])     

        # Calculate resize ratios
        x_ratio = 640 / original_width
        y_ratio = 640 / original_height   

        # Get the annotations (e.g., bounding boxes)
        annotation_ids = self.coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=image_id)
        annotations = self.coco.loadAnns(annotation_ids)

        bboxes, masks, categories = [], [], []

        for ann in annotations:
            # Add bounding boxes
            if "bbox" in ann:
                xmin, ymin, width, height = ann["bbox"][0]*x_ratio, ann["bbox"][1]*y_ratio, ann["bbox"][2]*x_ratio, ann["bbox"][3]*y_ratio
                if width == 0:
                    width = 1
                if height == 0:
                    height = 1
                bbox = [xmin, ymin, xmin + width, ymin + height]
                bboxes.append(bbox)
                
            # Add labels (category_id)
            categories.append(ann["category_id"])
                
            # Add masks (convert to binary masks using pycocotools)
            if "segmentation" in ann:
                mask = self.coco.annToMask(ann)
                mask = tf.image.resize(tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32), [640, 640])
                masks.append(mask)

        # Convert lists to tensors
        bboxes = tf.convert_to_tensor(bboxes, dtype=tf.float32)  # Shape: (num_boxes, 4)
        masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(masks, dtype=tf.float32) if masks else tf.zeros((0, 640, 640))  # Shape: (num_boxes, 640, 640)
        categories = tf.convert_to_tensor(categories, dtype=tf.int32)  # Shape: (num_boxes,)
    
        return img, bboxes, masks, categories

    

    def tf_load_image_and_annotations(self, image_id):
        tf.print(image_id) # for debugging
        return tf.py_function(self.load_image_and_annotations, [image_id], [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32])


    def get_dataset(self, batch_size=4, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
        # Create a tf.data.Dataset
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(self.img_ids)

        # Map image IDs to images and annotations
        dataset = dataset.map(self.tf_load_image_and_annotations, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

        # Shuffle, batch, and prefetch the data
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size).batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        return dataset
    
    
    def get_size(self):
        return len(self.img_ids)

The class is called (and the dataset created) with the code
coco_dataset = CocoDataset(val_ann_file, val_img_dir)
dataset = coco_dataset.get_dataset()

which loads the annotations into memory and creates the index.
When I want to see the content of the first batch with the following code
for batch in dataset.take(1):
    images, bboxes, masks, categories = batch
    print(images.shape)      # Expecting (batch_size, 640, 640, 3)
    print(bboxes.shape)      # Expecting (batch_size, num_boxes, 4)
    print(masks.shape)       # Expecting (batch_size, num_boxes, 640, 640)
    print(categories.shape)   # Expecting (batch_size, num_boxes)

I see the output (image-id's created with tf.print(image_id))
37777
6818
480985
.
.
.
522713
181666
2024-10-20 21:57:00.980492: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1827] INVALID_ARGUMENT: TypeError: Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.
Traceback (most recent call last):

What I really don't understand is the error message "Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor". I have the impression that the code in load_image_and_annotations(self, image_id) is not executed, but unfortunately I cannot solve the problem on my own. I would be very thankful for any help, suggestions and explanations!
